# Upload file to Azure Blob Storage from browser without SAS key

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I know uploads can be done to Azure Blob storage [using SAS keys](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/azure-storage-blob-upload-from-browser/ba-p/392687).

This works perfeclty fine in react

```js
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";
const account = env.REACT_APP_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME;
const sas = env.REACT_APP_BLOB_SAS;
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net${sas}`
const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(container);
const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(destination);
blockBlobClient.upload(data, data.size)
```

From what I understand, using SAS keys can be a security breach if any user is allowed to upload things after logging in. The SAS can't be made user-dependent, and if the SAS key is sniffed, it can open a security loophole in the application.

In Amazon, one can verify the user identity and access through Cognito, and then upload directly to S3. How can this be achieved using Azure Blob Storage and Azure AD?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? AAD auth to storage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory

Comment: @silent, yes. My question is how to do this using a browser (client). All guides and examples use SAS or connection string. I have not found any documentation supporting uploads from a browser (a web application, not the azure portal)

Comment: If you have a server-side component, then that component can authenticate to Storage using AAD. If you want upload directly from the browser, you need to integrate AAD login into your app first to get a token for the user which you can then use to interact with storage

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet) documentation to setup AAD for your application and then have a look at [THIS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob#create-the-blob-service-client) documentation which shows how to setup your BlobServiceClient with these credentials. [HERE](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/storage/storage-blob/samples/javascript/azureAdAuth.js) is an example from Github.

Another method is using the rest APIs.
You can authenticate on Azure Active directory first [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-azure-active-directory) to get a token. Pass this as bearer token in the [Putblob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) rest api call.

Comment: After much research, it looks like Azure disables authentication and upload to blob storage from a JavaScript client - unless you use a SAS key. I found that the best way is to send the data to a backend server with all keys, authenticate the request and then upload it to blob storage. 

Given that this answer aligns well with everything I have found, I'll accept it as an answer to the question.